# Approximating Pi with fractional log base. Coincidence?

Tags: logarithms, approximation, pi

In an attempt to understand logarithms better for an unrelated problem, I stumbled across the value of $\log_{9}(1000)$ is equal to approximately 3.143. I thought this was interesting, so tried to get a result closer to pi.

The closest I could get from playing around with a calculator is the log base (9+1/70) of 1000:

### $\log_{9.014285714285714}(1000)=3.141587$.

I think it is quite interesting that you can get a reasonable (within a few digits) approximation of pi this way, but am posting this here to ask if this is merely a coincidence, since it feels as if I am forcing the result slightly.

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Seems to be a coincidence.

Comment: If you choose $9+5/351$ or $9+6/421$ instead of $9+1/70$ , you get even better approximations for $\pi$. To understand this , look at the simple continued fraction of exp(log(1000)/Pi) which is [9,70,5,1,9,...]

Comment: Thank you very much for you response! I also had a look at the graph of the function $f(x)=\log_{x}(1000)$ and it's a bit more obvious that this is just a coincidence now. I just got excited seeing 3.14!